# java text file set line reader

Tags: java

I want to set line reader to first position , for example It just finished the reading whole text file and I want to set line reader to the position when it first started to read text file ?

I opened txt file using scanner

Is it possible?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. If "the position when it first started to read text file" is the start, the simplest approach is just to reopen the file...

Comment: The problem is I cannot reopen it.

Comment: have u closed it before opening?

Comment: @Hooman: It sounds like you have a lot more context than you've told us. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: so I can close it and reopen it to set line reader to start position,is there another way to that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner` itself has no way to rewind the input.  You might be able to `reset()` the underlying input stream, but that might not be supported depending on what stream implementation is being used.  Your best bet is to close and reopen the input.

EDIT:

If you cannot close/reopen the input, then try calling `reset()` on the underlying stream.